# Error in base::":"(from, to) : NA/NaN argument

Tags: r, regression, nan, ordinal

Trying to run ordinal logistic regression, and running into NA/ NaN argument. There are no NAs in the base data

code:

call:

```
polr( as.factor(reporting_score) ~ Plan.Pkg.hr, data = dat, Hess = TRUE)
```

where reporting_socre is an object and an ordinal variable (dependent) and Plan.Pkg.hr is a continuous variable (independent)

Can someone help with this error?